# Memcached (Dalli) and expiration time for caches_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

I'm using Memcached and Dalli store for my rails app.

Is there a way to set something like `expires_in` and `gzip` for `caches_action`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them to the `caches_action` invocation line as cache parameters; all parameters that are not specific to `caches_action` will be passed to the actual memcache `fetch` call.

```
caches_action :show, :unless => proc {current_user},
  :cache_path => proc {"post_#{params[:id]}"},
  :expires_in => 10.seconds,
  :race_condition_ttl => 2.seconds
```

I use Dalli and Rails 3.1.3, and this code works as intended.  I suppose, gzipping would also work.

Comment: Thanks so much, I stumbled upon another issue, the cache control header i set through `expires_in 1.month` inside the action seems to only work once when there is no cache, then memcached starts serving it with a `Cache-Control:must-revalidate, private, max-age=0` any idea why it doesn't remember the headers?

Comment: @Ryan - did you ever get an answer to the headers question?

Comment: FYI: dalli does not support race_condition_ttl: https://github.com/mperham/dalli/pull/277